# How to CONCATENATE 2 time datatypes in sqlserver 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to concatenate two time which is `start_time` AND `end_time` and I get this error:
 **Incorrect syntax near '+'.** What I'm missing? Here is my query

```
  SELECT schedule.sid AS [ID],
         doctor.dlname + ',' + doctor.dfname + ' ' + doctor.dmname AS [Physician],
         schedule.sday AS [Day],
         start_time + '-' + end_time , <----I get the error here
         doctor.rate AS [Rate] ,schedule.sstatus AS [Status] 
         FROM schedule INNER JOIN doctor ON schedule.did = doctor.did
```

Comment: Maybe you should cast them to string. AFAIK we only concatenate strings, not times.

Comment: Oh thanks I figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this... You need to `CAST` `start_time` and `end_time` first before concatenating them as only `string` datatype is allowed to be concatenated.

```
SELECT schedule.sid AS [ID],
       doctor.dlname + ',' + doctor.dfname + ' ' + doctor.dmname AS [Physician],
       schedule.sday AS [Day],
       CAST(start_time AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(end_time AS VARCHAR),
       doctor.rate AS [Rate] ,schedule.sstatus AS [Status] 
FROM schedule 
INNER JOIN doctor 
ON schedule.did = doctor.did
```

Alternatively... you can use `CONVERT` too...

```
SELECT schedule.sid AS [ID],
       doctor.dlname + ',' + doctor.dfname + ' ' + doctor.dmname AS [Physician],
       schedule.sday AS [Day],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, start_time) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, end_time),
       doctor.rate AS [Rate] ,schedule.sstatus AS [Status] 
FROM schedule 
INNER JOIN doctor 
ON schedule.did = doctor.did
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   schedule.sid AS [ID]
        ,doctor.dlname + ',' + doctor.dfname + ' ' + doctor.dmname AS [Physician]
        ,schedule.sday AS [Day]
        ,CAST(start_time AS VARCHAR(8)) + '-' + CAST(end_time AS VARCHAR(8))  <----I get the error here
        ,doctor.rate AS [Rate] 
        ,schedule.sstatus AS [Status] 
FROM schedule INNER JOIN doctor 
ON schedule.did = doctor.did
```

start_time is Time/Datetime datatype and `'-'` is a string which is varchar datatype. to concatenate two values you have to get them in the same datatype. Simply convert your concertinaing columns into character datatype.

Converting your time fields to VARCHAR(8) will return a string something like `23:13:05`.